# Call a contract method that accepts bytes memory as input with Foundry Cast

Tags: solidity, foundry

For a function like below:

```
function approveAndCallcode(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes memory _extraData) public {
    allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    bool success;
    (success,) = _spender.call(_extraData);
}
```

Is it possible to call it with foundry `cast send` command?

`cast send 0x.. "approveAndCallcode(address,uint256,bytes memory)" 0x.. 7 "abi.encodeWithSignature("transfer(address,uint256)", address(alice), 1000)" - -rpc-url $THE_RPC_URL --private-key $thePrivateKey1`

Answer (score 1):

You are right at certain point but, some corrections that i made.

```
  cast send <contract-address> "approveAndCallcode(address,uint256,bytes)" <spender-address> <value> "$(abi.encodeWithSignature('transfer(address,uint256)', address(alice), 1000))" --rpc-url $THE_RPC_URL --private-key $thePrivateKey1
```